# Автоматический переход к якорю на загруженный ajax контент

Tags: jquery

Не на гуглил, как не старался :(

Есть динамически генерируемый ajax-ом контент, на который, после загрузки оного нужно доскроллить БЕЗ КЛИКА.

Есть куча решений через on("click", ) - но у меня не происходит клика - нужно доскролить до нужного якоря при загрузке страницы, как быть?

например,

```
var el = "#review-1261";
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(el).offset().top }, "slow");
```

при этом блок `<div id="review-1261"></div>` загружен через ajax

консоль ругается:

> jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of
> undefined (reading 'top')

Comment: только что идея пришла, сделать в коде <a href="#review-1261" class=".review-1261"></a> и генерировать клик по нему после загрузки и обаратывать через  .on(click, )  - то это грабли... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение:

```
function scrolingto()
  {
  var el = "#review-111";
  $("html, body").on("click", el, function ()
    {
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(el).offset().top-100 }, "slow");
    });
  $(el).trigger("click");
  }
setTimeout(scrolingto, 1000);
```